# (Number | undefined)[] is not assignable to Number[]

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, array.prototype.map

I'm having a problem with types in typescript.

So i have an array of som ID's i get from some checkboxes. This array could also be empty.

example of values that can be returned from submit():

```
const responseFromSubmit = {
1: {
  id: "1",
  value: "true"
  },
2: {
  id: "2",
  value: "false"
  },
3: {
  id: "3",
  value: "false"
  } 
};



const Ids: number[] = Object.values(submit()!)
  .map(formfield => {
    if (formfield.value === 'true') {
      return Number(formfield.id);
    }
  })
  .filter(id => id != undefined);
```

So in this case the Ids would be Ids = [1].

I have tried several solution like trying to change the value of Ids after the codeblock above by checking if Ids is undefined:

```
if (ids.length > 0){
  ids = []
}
```

Through this code the constant Ids is type of (Number | undefined)[], how can i make it always be of type number[] even if its empty?

Here is a solution, but I dont like it at all:

```
const Ids: number[] = Object.values(submit()!)
  .map(formfield => {
    if (formfield.value === 'true') {
      return Number(formfield.id);
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  })
  .filter(id => id != 0);
```

In my case the formfield.id will never have value 0, so it is possible to filter all elements with the value 0. So I would not recomend this solution. but hey, it works, right?  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The issue is that `.filter` *cannot* change the type of the array. It makes sense, say, you have `arr = [1, 2, "a", "b", 3]` which is `(number | string)[]`. If you do `arr.filter(x => x !== "a")` that's *the same* operation (signature-wise) as `arr.filter(x => typeof x === "number")`. There is no way for TS to deduce that one filter will produce `number[]` and the other wouldn't. It would need to examine the code and likely be able to do more advanced analysis than this.

Comment: What is `submit()` ?

Comment: submit() is  a function that I made, it returns values from a form. In this case it returns all values from the checkboxes :)

Comment: How about the case of 0? Do you want to filter it out as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The problem

The main issue is the `.filter()` signature. It will *always* return an array of the same type as what you begun with. It is not possible for the TypeScript compiler to guaranteed anything else. Here is an example:

```js
const arr/*: (string | number) */ = ["one", 2, 3, "four", 5, 6];

const numbers/*: number[]*/ = arr.filter(x => typeof x === "number");

console.log(numbers);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQLhgCmgglmA5jAHxjAFcBbAIwFMEBKAbQF0YBeGegInCo4BoYATPwDM-DgDMQJBHxgBWfgDZGAbgCwAKE2hIsUpRoRU+6giat4SAHTisAGyg00AD1YA+GFACeAByohxGFcWEJgOExoOWnUtDR0IEDsqKzsQXDQIhAhooA)

This *works* if you disregard types but it's functionally equivalent to the following:

```js
const arr/*: (string | number)[]*/ = ["one", 2, 3, "four", 5, 6];

const numbers/*: number[]*/ = arr.filter(x => x !== "one");

console.log(numbers);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQLhgCmgglmA5jAHxjAFcBbAIwFMEBKAbQF0YBeGegInCo4BoYATPwDM-DgDMQJBHxgBWfgDZGAbgCwAKE2hIsUpRoRU+6giat4SAHTisAGyg00AD1YA+GK4CELNlzA8tOpaGjoQIHZUVnYguGgmhkFAA)

In both cases you have an array of mixed types and *some* filtering function. In order to guarantee that the result would be only a specific type, you need to examine the code and make inferences. This is not how the compiler works, however - calling `.filter()` on `Array<T | U>` can only produce `Array<T | U>` again, the generic is unchanged.

## Solution

What you can do is flip the order of your `.map` and `.filter`. You'll need to re-write them but it will work correctly in term of types. I also makes the logic more coherent - right now you are *double* filtering implicitly. The `map()` will only transform some types, not others, thus doing an indirect filter. The actual `.filter()` call then sieves the unmapped/soft-filtered values.

The correct logic and correct type preservation would thus be the following:

```
const Ids: number[] = Object.values(submit()!)
  .filter(formfield => formfield.value === 'true')
  .map(formfield => Number(formfield.id))
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAXAngBwQZQPYFsQBU0EBeeAb3gDcoIBXEALngHJEZ7n4AfFgMxoDOIZgBp4AS2BMBbcQDsA5vAC+AbgCwAKFCRYCFOngAlEANRY5QgGIxcGWgCMc4xPHikKAbQDWIZEzlaHAcQGABdJmw8QnRPMJUNTS0daDh4Xlo5MERxC3gBR2dEAAoASiYTMwtrWxx7JxdueECICETk8FSEDKycvOo6UwAefAA+YvlUWkQmfHL4fB8-LF4FsPbNAHpNgHkHACtwRAA6AfoBMvhgLFNmrFcAdywYb3goAXhTACYABgBGADs8Ag4gc8AAFu8kFh4CE3sBQMBYdMJIhmB85Pd4OYBAJQRAEODQiAtNsBDC8ThaNAcookODxB8Hi5wW8qDRzpcetlcnJ6VBXJCPiAAI60cQDEByVx4hRyAXTEmaMDVVwASWAAgCQRCMDi7ngmwAVHtDtljkbNmdTMUCg0SqUAISlLRuY68cQQRChYq8Z44D0gCBI4ijdL+wPB04ckjEUisdjCF2aN04KCoX0R8RBkNhgByOp9fpgAezUckpVKQA)

This is shorter and more correct form of the logic you want.

- The real filtering condition `formfield.value === 'true'` is extracted by itself in the `.filter()` call.
- `.filter()` runs *first* so you're guaranteed to have the have the same types from compiler perspective *and* you've just shrunk the list to only the items you're interested in.
- `.map()` not does exactly what it's meant to - a 1:1 mapping for each value of the array. It doesn't need to do any logic more complex. So, it doesn't need to concern itself with what is or isn't correct in order to carry out the transformation.

Comment: Thank you! this is a solution that work perfect. Your explanation was so clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
    if (formfield.value === 'true') {
      return Number(formfield.id);
    }
    return null;
```

under the return in the if.

The complete code:

```
const Ids: number[] = Object.values(submit()!)
  .map(formfield => {
    if (formfield.value === 'true') {
      return Number(formfield.id);
    }
    return null;
  })
  .filter(id => id != undefined);
```

EDIT:

A better way to check if one variable is undefined is with `typeof` operator:

```
typeof id !== 'undefined'
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! This will change the type to (number | null)[]

Comment: Yes, this still doesn't work in with strict compiler options. It only works if you accept `null` as member of `number` (at loose compiler checks) but I don't think this is desirable.

Comment: Can you give us the array of data that comes out of submit()? In order to do some tests. Edit the question to do it.

Comment: @aepifano it's very easy to test [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAXAngBwQZQPYFsQBU0EBeeAb3gDcoIBXEALngGdEYBLAOwHMAaedsCasOPeAF8A3AFgAUKEiwEAM1qcwidlk4taAIxztEACgCUTbHkLoA2gF14AH3idaECDNlyw21vACSwMxMrjh6IDD28KTM+oYmpgCEcvDwAHQ4UKjGylgwOMrsIBDA0QB85CmpAsrwOXkFRSVp1HQkxKQA5Gz0naaVstXVcIi0MDoAcrRhEfX5hcXAaYKmnkPiVakjYzqu7msSpnJAA). I've removed some of the irrelevant details. The important thing is that it's It's working with an array of types then transforming them. The `Object.values` is unnecessary to see the typings.

Comment: I edited the question to have an example of the response

Comment: Thanks. Strange, it seems to work.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ids-from-submit-values?file=index.ts
The result is: [] if you haven't true values and [1] in your example.

Comment: @aepifano stackblitz erros on `Object.values` because you have to add it as a library to the compiler options. I don't really know that can be done on that platform, though. At any rate, it also doesn't have strict type checking on: compare [stackblits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kx899q) and [the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAdgrgtgLmvARiAThAvBAjAbgFgAoWObZYYI0+CmKAExADMBLKERmoA). The latter does have strict type checks.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the tip on Object. I don't know how to use https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/.
I'll try it.
I am more skilled with Angular (and stackblitz with it).

Comment: I don't really know how to add the es2017 lib for either of these. It will clear up the error with `Object.values`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question directly, but allow me to suggest a different approach:

```
const ids = Object.keys( obj || {} )
      .reduce( function(acc,cur) {
                   if( obj[cur] ) acc.push(cur);
                   return acc
                },
                []
              )
```

It sounds like you want to extract a subset of values from your object. This will return the keys that are truthy. Instead of `acc.push(cur)` you would want to push the equivalent of `Number(formfield.id)`. The `obj || {}` at the top allows 'obj' to be `undefined`.